# Generate Month Name, Day name, Week number and Day number between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, calendar

I have two date variables and I want to present the data in specific manner. So, my query is like this that shows the months name,

```
    SELECT TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (start_date, LEVEL - 1), 'fmMonth') months_namE
      FROM (SELECT DATE '2012-01-01' start_date, DATE '2012-03-25' end_date
              FROM DUAL)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                MONTHS_BETWEEN (TRUNC (end_date, 'MM'),
                                TRUNC (start_date, 'MM'))
              * +1;
```

and the output is like this,

```
MONTHS_NAME
-----------
January
February
```

my intended output is like this

```
MONTHS_NAME | WEEK | DAYS
-------------------------
January        1      1
January        1      2 
January        1      3 
January        1      4
January        1      5
January        1      6
January        1      7   
January        2      1
January        3
January        4
```

i tried numerous methods and cant make it work, please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be easy using **Row Generator** method. Rest is only the **format mask**.

> - **fmMonth** - Month name
> - **fmDay**   - Day name
> - **IW**      - Week Number
> - **D**       - Day Number

In **SQL*Plus**, my demo is between the dates **'2012-01-01'** and **'2012-02-20'**:

```
SQL> def date_start = '2012-01-01'
SQL> def date_end   = '2012-02-20'
SQL>
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT to_date('&date_start', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date1,
  3      to_date('&date_end', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date2
  4    FROM dual
  5    )
  6  SELECT TO_CHAR(date1+LEVEL-1, 'fmMonth') month_name,
  7         TO_CHAR(date1+LEVEL-1, 'fmDay') day_name,
  8         TO_CHAR(date1+LEVEL-1, 'IW') the_week,
  9         TO_CHAR(date1+level-1, 'D') the_day
 10  FROM data
 11    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= date2-date1+1
 12  /
old   2:   (SELECT to_date('&date_start', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date1,
new   2:   (SELECT to_date('2012-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date1,
old   3:     to_date('&date_end', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date2
new   3:     to_date('2012-02-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD') date2
```

**Result**

```
MONTH_NAME DAY_NAME  THE_WEEK THE_DAY
---------- --------- -------- -------
January    Sunday    52       1
January    Monday    01       2
January    Tuesday   01       3
January    Wednesday 01       4
January    Thursday  01       5
January    Friday    01       6
January    Saturday  01       7
January    Sunday    01       1
January    Monday    02       2
January    Tuesday   02       3
January    Wednesday 02       4
January    Thursday  02       5
January    Friday    02       6
January    Saturday  02       7
January    Sunday    02       1
January    Monday    03       2
January    Tuesday   03       3
January    Wednesday 03       4
January    Thursday  03       5
January    Friday    03       6
January    Saturday  03       7
January    Sunday    03       1
January    Monday    04       2
January    Tuesday   04       3
January    Wednesday 04       4
January    Thursday  04       5
January    Friday    04       6
January    Saturday  04       7
January    Sunday    04       1
January    Monday    05       2
January    Tuesday   05       3
February   Wednesday 05       4
February   Thursday  05       5
February   Friday    05       6
February   Saturday  05       7
February   Sunday    05       1
February   Monday    06       2
February   Tuesday   06       3
February   Wednesday 06       4
February   Thursday  06       5
February   Friday    06       6
February   Saturday  06       7
February   Sunday    06       1
February   Monday    07       2
February   Tuesday   07       3
February   Wednesday 07       4
February   Thursday  07       5
February   Friday    07       6
February   Saturday  07       7
February   Sunday    07       1
February   Monday    08       2

51 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks lalit this is awesome. And how do i add the day name for each date occurence ?

Comment: Use `fmday`. Please mark it answered, would help others as well.

Comment: Updated the answer with the day name as well.