# fiscal year date sequence generation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table called fiscal year with column start_date,end_date(empty table), I want to insert records for each fiscal year till 2060

FISCAL_YEAR  Start dt is  Jul 1st, End dt is Jun 31st of next year

what i tried

```
select  add_months(start_date ,-6),add_months(start_date ,6)-1 from (
select to_date('20000101','yyyymmdd') start_date from dual )
 basis
```

how do i generate this sequence till 2060

```
 Decription              start_date        end_date  
 FISCAL YEAR 2000     7/1/1999              6/30/2000
```

Comment: It's going to be difficult: June has only 30 days!

Comment: See http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/04/15/generate-date-month-name-week-number-day-number-between-two-dates-in-oracle-sql/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate Month Name, Day name, Week number and Day number between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646165/generate-month-name-day-name-week-number-and-day-number-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SQL> select
  2    to_date('01-07-' || (1999 + rownum), 'dd.mm.yyyy') start_date,
  3    to_date('30-06-' || (2000 + rownum), 'dd.mm.yyyy') finish_date
  4  from dual
  5  connect by level <= 10;

START_DATE  FINISH_DATE
----------- -----------
01.07.2000  30.06.2001
01.07.2001  30.06.2002
01.07.2002  30.06.2003
01.07.2003  30.06.2004
01.07.2004  30.06.2005
01.07.2005  30.06.2006
01.07.2006  30.06.2007
01.07.2007  30.06.2008
01.07.2008  30.06.2009
01.07.2009  30.06.2010

10 rows selected
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT 
   ADD_MONTHS(DATE '1999-07-01', 12*(LEVEL-1)) as fiscal_year_begin,
   ADD_MONTHS(DATE '1999-07-01', 12*LEVEL) - INTERVAL '1' DAY AS fiscal_year_end
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 60;

FISCAL_YEAR_BEGIN   FISCAL_YEAR_END
1999-07-01  2000-06-30
2000-07-01  2001-06-30
2001-07-01  2002-06-30
2002-07-01  2003-06-30
2003-07-01  2004-06-30
2004-07-01  2005-06-30
2005-07-01  2006-06-30
2006-07-01  2007-06-30
2007-07-01  2008-06-30
2008-07-01  2009-06-30
...
```