# Get query result 15 second interval in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sum, recursive-query

I have following query to get 15 seconds interval. However I want to show also '0' values even if the result doesn't have value.

Here is the Query;

```
select to_char(trunc(sample_time,'hh24') + (trunc(to_char(sample_time,'mi')/1)*1)/1440 + (trunc(to_char(sample_time,'ss')/15)*15)/86400,'hh24:mi:ss') as SAMPLE_TIME,nvl(wait_class,'CPU') as waits,round(count(*)/15,2)
from gv$active_session_history
where sample_time >= sysdate-60/1440
group by wait_class,to_char(trunc(sample_time,'hh24') + (trunc(to_char(sample_time,'mi')/1)*1)/1440  + (trunc(to_char(sample_time,'ss')/15)*15)/86400,'hh24:mi:ss')
order by 1 desc,3 desc;
```

The result is;

```
SAMPLE_TIME    WAITS   COUNT
-----------------------------
14:59:30        CPU     3
14:59:00        CPU     2    
14:58:45        CPU     2
14:58:30        CPU     1
14:58:15        CPU     2
14:57:45        CPU     2
```

What i want is this;

```
    SAMPLE_TIME    WAITS   COUNT
    -----------------------------
    14:59:30        CPU     3
    14:59:15        CPU     0  // Added 14:59:15    
    14:59:00        CPU     2    
    14:58:45        CPU     2
    14:58:30        CPU     1
    14:58:15        CPU     2
    14:58:00        CPU     0  // Added 14:59:15
    14:57:45        CPU     2
```

What should i change from above query?

Comment: Thanks John.  It sounds like date(time)-generation is what you are looking for.  A common approach to this kind of thing is to generate the dates, then outer join the fixed dates to the optional data.  This shows up frequently on stack-overflow, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231374/sql-trunc-group-order-by-dates-day-month-quarter-year-with-sum-skip-dates-with, or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893963/fiscal-year-date-sequence-generation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery as follows to generate the list of all dates within the last hour with a 15 seconds interval :

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'mi') - 15*level/(60*60*24) 
from dual
connect by level < 60*60/15;
```

Inserted that in your query :

```
with a as (
    select trunc(sysdate, 'mi') - 15*level/(60*60*24) as sample_time 
    from dual 
    connect by level < 60*60/15
)
select 
    a.sample_time,
    nvl(wait_class,'cpu') as waits,
    round(sum(decode(ash.wait_class, null, 0, 1))/15,2)
from a
left join gv$active_session_history ash 
    on ash.sample_time between a.sample_time and a.sample_time + 15/(60*60*24)
group by a.sample_time, wait_class
order by 1 desc,3 desc;
```